# Plasma hangs when I try to switch desktops

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kde, multiple-desktops

Kubuntu 18.

When I try to switch to another desktop, it sometimes (1 out of 7 or 8 times) results in Plasma dying, active window still works, but all windows have no window titles, and most of the system shortcuts (e.g `alt+tab` and such) doesn't work, only the custom ones do and `ctrl+alt+f1-f7`. When I try to

```
killall plasma5
kstart plasmashell
```

It doesn't help, system still won't work, and only `sudo reboot` solves the problem. What is that? An X11 issue?

/edit :
I managed to make a screenshot.
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvguM.jpg)

Also I excluded everything in `kdebugdialog` except for plasma and libplasma, `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors` and the only suspicious looking string I got after crash is:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
after 3494908 requests (3494908 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

So it could be a nvidia driver issue, probably? No idea how it is even connected.

I checked `journalctl -xe` aswell, but it keeps silence.

/edit2 `systemctl restart sddm.service` (X server restart) actually helps, but it kills all the loaded applications.

Answer (score 3):

OK, got it, it is kwin dying for some reason.

If you have the same issue, you may press alt+f2 or alt+space or whatever your hotkey for executing a command is and

```
kwin_x11
```

restarts kwin. Since the issue doesn't happen too often, I am satisfied with this workaround.

Comment: I am running into this exact same problem on Kubuntu 18.04.1. Your workaround also works for me, do you know what causes it or maybe you found a proper solution? In case not, we can try and fill a bug report together somewhere with our system info and crash log.

Comment: My symptoms seem to be even worse: kwin_x11 is still running but won't respond, so I have to switch to a text terminal (ctrl-alt-F2), log in, 'killall -9 kwin_x11', then start kwin manually: "DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority kwin &". Also running nvidia proprietary drivers on Kubuntu 18.04.